# Are the limits of a.e. equal sequences of measurable functions equal a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I haven't seen the following fact in any textbook or reference, which either means that it is trivial, or that it's false. Hopefully it is the former. I've attempted a proof:

---

**Claim**: Let $f_n, g_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be sequences of measurable functions such that for every $n \in \mathbb N^+$, $f_n = g_n$ almost everywhere (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure). Furthermore, suppose $f = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$ and $g = \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n$. Then $f = g$ almost everywhere.

**Purported Proof**: For any $n$, let $E_n$ be the set on which $f_n$ and $g_n$ differ. Let $E = \cup_n E_n$. Then $E$ is the countable union of sets of zero measure, and therefore is of measure zero itself.

$f_n - g_n$ converges to $f - g$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ since $f_n$ and $g_n$ converge. For any $x \not \in E$, $f_n(x) - g_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$. Therefore $f(x) - g(x) = 0$ except on $E$. Hence $f = g$ almost everywhere

---

Is this claim in fact true?

Comment: Your proof is correct. (one minor thing: Ι guess at the line above the last you meant to write $(f_n-g_n)$ converges etc. By the way, you could have even had a.e. convergence for the sequences $(f_n),~(g_n).$

Comment: Great! Thanks for the correction to the proof, as well -- I've edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is true, and you have the right proof.

A minor correction is that it would be better to write $f(x)=g(x)$ instead of $f(x)-g(x)=0$. The truth is that your proof works even if the limits are $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know that the proof can be made more general.